# How to call a gradle method from a groovy script

Tags: gradle, groovy

Is it possible to call a 'ext.' gradle method from a groovy script?

Here is the an example of a gradle ext.method I am trying to call
(File: codec.gradle)

```
ext.encrypt = { param ->
  generateKey()
  String encryptedMessage = encryptAES(param)

  println("--ENCRYPTION--")
  println("password: "+param)
  println("key: "+key)
  println("Encrypted message: "+encryptedMessage)

  return encryptedMessage
}
```

What i want to do is call it from a groovy script like this one:
(File: TestGradleReference.groovy)

I am imagining something like this

```
apply from: "script/codec.gradle"
String encryptVal = project.encrypt('password')
println("Encrypted value: " + encryptVal)
```

however this doesn't work

What is the best way (if possible) to call a gradle method from a groovy script?

Comment: What do you mean by _"doesn't work"_?  You tried `ext.encrypt('password')`?

Comment: yes i have. I can't reference methods from codec.gradle or any other gradle file from a groovy script. That is the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not possible

```
ext.encrypt
```

are only accessible from gradle files